# eclipse is not launching android sdk

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

Please help. I am facing this issue:

My eclipse no longer launches the android sdk properly and gives the following error message

`[2013-10-20 23:08:09 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:`

`Error: Missing platform-tools
Warning: Ignoring platform 'android-18': build.prop is missing.`

Comment: You need to go into the Android SDK and download build-tools. I assume you just updated the SDK to API level 18?

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded the Android bundle. Ive downloaded the build tools and corrected the android SDK path.. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the Android SDK package downloader and download the build-tools. When the SDK went to API Level 18, they decoupled the build-tools and made them another download.